# How to generate non terminating error for advanced functions in powershell

Tags: powershell

I want to have some function like below

```
function get-diskinfo {
    [string[]]$ComputerName
        # some stuff here
}
```

so I can use it like

```
get-diskinfo -ComputerName com1,com2,com3
if (!$?) { # I want to caller to check this, so the experience is same as built-in cmdlet
    write-error "failed to get disk info for some computer"
}
```

however after googling, still no idea to generate non terminating error from get-diskinfo, any idea how to do this? thank you in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As it stands, your function isn't an advanced function yet.  Change it to this to make it an advanced function:

```
function Get-DiskInfo {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=0)]
        [Alias("CN")]
        [ValidateNotNull()]
        [string[]]
        $ComputerName
    )
    ...
}
```

Being a real advanced function is necessary in order to get access to `$pscmdlet`.  To write a non-terminating error use `$pscmdlet.WriteError()`.  You can get fancy and do something like this:

```
$ex = new-object System.Management.Automation.ItemNotFoundException "Cannot find path '$Path' because it does not exist."
$category = [System.Management.Automation.ErrorCategory]::ObjectNotFound
$errRecord = new-object System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord $ex, "PathNotFound", $category, $Path
$psCmdlet.WriteError($errRecord)
```

Answer (score 1):

In general, use the `Write-Error` cmdlet to create non-terminating errors, or as Keith showed you, use the pscmdlet.WriteError method. In any case, you must catch any terminating errors that occurred in your code, use the `try and catch` blocks, and instead emit non-terminating errors using one of the above methods.

For more information see the `about_Try_Catch_Finally` help topic.